# Is it possible that $A\subseteq A\times B$ for some non empty sets $A,B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if there exist two non empty sets $A,B$ such that
$$A\subseteq A\times B.$$
I know that always exists a subset of $A\times B$ with the same cardinality of $A$, but i'm requesting here that $A$ is a subset of $A\times B$ without using any identification map. 
At first i thought that this was not possible because $A$ and $B\times A$ are two sets containing different kind of elements: the second contains pairs like $(a,b)$ with $a\in A, b\in B$; the first just single elements $a\in A$. Moreover, suppose $A\subseteq A\times B$ holds and take $a \in A$. Then $a=(a_1,b_1)$ for some $a_1 \in A, b_1\in B$. For the same reason $a_1=(a_2,b_2)$ and so $a=((a_2,b_2),b_1)$. Following this argument I got some sort of recursive infinite definition for $a$ that made me suspect something is wrong. However if I take $$A=\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} ;B=\mathbb{N}$$
is it true that $A=A\times B$ or I'm missing something? Moreover, if $A\subseteq A\times B$ can be true, are there other examples?

edit: I add another strange example: take $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{N}^i $ and $B=\mathbb{N}$, then $A \times B \subset A$. This makes me think that maybe exists also an example for the other inclusion.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $A\subseteq A\times B$ because $A$ would live in a smaller dimension than $A\times B$.

Comment: You can identify $A$ with a subset of $A\times B$, like for example you can fix $b\in B$ and then do $a\mapsto (a,b)$, but without any such association $A$ cannot be a subset of $A\times B$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I'm not convinced that either of those intuitions works for infinite products.

Comment: I thought the same, but like i said, if $A=\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\times...$(countable product) then why is if false that $A\times \mathbb{N}=A$?

Comment: @mrprottolo I think you're confusing whether something is equal to $A$ with whether it is just isomorphic to $A$ (as sets).

Comment: @Gregory: That has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's no way to make sense of $A\subseteq A\times B$ without some identification.

Comment: @Gregory: Yes, there is. $A\times B$ is a set of ordered pairs. $A$ is a set. It makes perfect sense to ask whether or not $A\subseteq A\times B$. It makes no sense if you think about $A$ being a set of real numbers or whatever. But sets are not limits to being sets of real numbers.

Comment: Let $X^1=X$, $X^{n}=X^{n-1} \times X$ and define $A=\cup\{X^{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then $A\times X = \cup\{X^{n+1}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ so that the reverse can be true.

Comment: I think this is ruled out by the Axiom of Regularity: it would let you construct a chain $\ldots \in x \in y \in z \in\ldots$ that has no first element. But you _can_ have $A \times B \subseteq A$: let $B = \{b\}$, and $A = \{ a, (a,b), ((a,b),b), (((a,b),b),b),\ldots\}$. (Edit: I see now that @Nex has another construction that proves the same thing.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The existence of sets $A$ and $B$ with $A\subseteq A\times B$ contradicts the axiom of regularity (or the axiom of foundation.)  The precise proof depends on which construction of $A\times B$ you prefer.  We will use the most common formulation, in which we represent the ordered pair $(a,b)$ by the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, but the proof easily adapts to other constructions.

Suppose $A\subseteq A\times B$.  Since the sets are nonempty, we can pick $a_0\in A$.  By assumption, we can write $a_0=(a_1,b_1)$ with $a_1\in A$ and $b_1\in B$, and continuing on we can write $a_i=(a_{i+1},b_{i+1})$.  Under our formulation of the cartesian product, this means $a_{i+1}\in \{a_{i+1}\}\in a_i$.

This gives an infinite descending sequence
$$ \cdots \in a_{i+1}\in \{a_{i+1}\}\in a_i \in \{a_i\}\in a_{i-1}\cdots \in a_0,$$
contradicting the axiom of foundation.

Answer (score 1):

An element of $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is an infinite sequence of natural numbers.  Buy what do we mean by a sequence.  $n_0,n_1,\ldots n_k,\ldots$ is really nothing more than a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.  For example, $f(k)=n_k$.

So, $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}=\{f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\}$.  So, what is an element of $A\times\Bbb N$?  It is a pair $(f,n)$. The are not elements of $A$.

Comment: I see wich is the problem. So is $A \subseteq A \times B$ always false? If so, how can one prove it?

Comment: It's neither true nor false, the question itself does not make sense.

Comment: @GregoryGrant  Given any two sets $A$ and $B$, we can always ask if $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Well okay then it's trivially false, and not very interesting.

Comment: @GregoryGrant  Well it is inuitively obvious, but proving it rigorously is not so easy.

Comment: @mrprottolo  I'm not sure how to formally prove this but I suspect that such a proof would involve the Axiom of Regularity aka Axiom of Foundation.  I'll think on this some more when I have time.

Comment: @Gregory Grant. Set theorists usually define the ordered pair $(a,b)$ as the set $\{a, \{a,b\}\}.$ So it's a valid Q....It may depend on the Axiom of Foundation.