# How to prove that if $A\subseteq A\times A$, then $A=\varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove that $A\subseteq (A \times A)\rightarrow A = \varnothing$  in axiomatic set theory?

This is theorem 107 of Patrick Suppes "*Axiomatic Set Theory*". I do not buy his argument that the set $A$ does not contain any empty sets because, according to him, the set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$. Are there any other arguments that prove this theorem? Why does the set $A$ not have the empty set as a member?

Comment: First, "does not contain ANY empty sets": there is only one empty set (extensionality). Second, what does $A\subseteq A\times A$ have to do with it? How could this possibly imply that $\emptyset \in A$? Every set *includes* the empty set ($\emptyset \subseteq A$), but that does not mean *contains* ($\in$).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516538/is-it-possible-that-a-subseteq-a-times-b-for-some-non-empty-sets-a-b

Comment: I do not buy his argument that the set A does not contain any empty sets. This means that ∅∉ A.

Comment: @EricBrown We can't possibly have $\emptyset\in A$ if $A\subseteq A\times A$, since $\emptyset$ is not an ordered pair (every element of $A$ has to be an ordered pair since $A\subseteq A\times A$). Of course this depends on the ordered pairing notion we're using ... but so does the result itself.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $A\subseteq A\times A$ and $A$ is nonempty. Pick an element $a$ of $A$ of minimal rank. Then $a=(b, c)$ for some $b, c\in A$, since every element of $A$ is an ordered pair of elements of $A$ (this is just "$A\subseteq A\times A$" in words).

But then $b$ and $c$ each have rank strictly less than that of $a$, which is a contradiction.

---

Note that this depends on the precise definition of the pairing function; for some pairing functions we may in fact have $A\subseteq A\times A$ for nonempty $A$. In particular, maybe we choose to represent the pair $\langle 17, 17\rangle$ by $17$; then $A=\{17\}$ satisfies $A=A\times A$. The result Suppes states is wihtin the context of one of the usual ordered pair notions.

Comment: What is the definition of "minimal rank"? Is it applied to an element or to a set? Thank you.

Comment: @manooooh The *rank* $rk(x)$ of a set $x$ (remember, in ZFC *everything* is a set - elements of sets are themselves sets) is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\in V_\alpha$, where $V_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th level of the [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe). It follows from the axiom of regularity (or foundation) that every set has a (unique) rank. Since the ordinals are well-founded, any nonempty set $X$ (here, we look at $X=A$) there is some $x\in X$ such that $rk(x)\le rk(y)$ for all $y\in X$.