# How to show that if $A \subseteq A \times A$ then $A = \emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems easy, but I have no idea on how to prove. Since $A \times A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, I was thinking to show that if $A \neq \emptyset$, then $A \nsubseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, but I didn't got any solid argument on this.

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe contraposition? But I just roughly though about it? Is it clear that $a \neq (a,a)$? Yes, right?

Comment: You need to use the axiom of foundation.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516538/is-it-possible-that-a-subseteq-a-times-b-for-some-non-empty-sets-a-b).

Comment: I love how "complicated" this "morally obvious" stuffs gets, once one really uses the set axioms.